# Typescript return type based on class type

Tags: typescript

I have the following classes set up with Typescript:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
  id: string | number;

  getIdPlusOne() {
    if (typeof this.id === 'number') {
      return this.id + 1;
    }

    return this.id + '1';
  }
}

class User extends BaseClass {
  id: number;
}

class Book extends BaseClass {
  id: string;
}
```

Now, obviously calling `getIdPlusOne` on a `User` instance would return a number, and on a `Book` instance would return a string. But Typescript doesn't know that, because the function itself returns `string | number`

Is there a way to make the compiler know that `new User().getIdPlusOne()` would always return a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Side note: I use the `--strict` compiler flag, which wants [class properties to be initialized](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization).  You're not doing that in your code so I was getting errors.  Therefore I will use the [definite assignment assertion operator `!`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) to suppress those warnings in the below code. )

This looks like a job for [polymorphic `this` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types).  You could annotate the return type of `getIdPlusOne()` in your base class to `this['id']`, which means "[look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the `id` property of the `this` type in whatever subclass of `BaseClass` the caller is using":

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    id!: string | number;

    getIdPlusOne(): this['id'] {
        if (typeof this.id === 'number') {
            return this.id + 1;
        }

        return this.id + '1';
    }
}
```

Note: sometimes the compiler will complain because it's hard to verify in a superclass that something is assignable to `this` in all possible subclasses; if so you might need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or two to get it working.  In the above case though the compiler seems to be okay with returning `this.id + 1` or `this.id + '1'` and having it be of type `this['id']`... but it's not really enforcing safety here.  You could change your `typeof this.id === 'number'` check to `typeof this.id !== 'number'` and it would still compile; so be careful!

---

Anyway now your subclasses will behave as expected, I think:

```
class User extends BaseClass {
    id!: number;
}
const u = new User();
u.id = 1;
u.getIdPlusOne().toFixed(); // okay
```

and

```
class Book extends BaseClass {
    id!: string;
}
const b = new Book();
b.id = "";
b.getIdPlusOne().toUpperCase(); // okay
```

The return type of `getIdPlusOne()` in each case is narrowed to the same type as the `id` type.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgYVXQQG8BYAKASoQEsATAQgC4FIoaA7AcwQB8EOAVwC2IHFADcFCtQRccEAJJ0ACskFgA8hxwAKAJQsIACxpgA2gHJ6lgLokZs6jQBmCXRACeABxwB7NxMzADp6BABeSIRLIVFxS30HSicUqAVBKA4EILBQugQAagQARilklIBfaXKnNIgMrJy8wujiyzLZKvIuhAoUNAwAVTBxBBwADwgcDjoMbBGCAaTZemYBETFJCi6+vw5IBEEIgRwAdwRh8QMywWbwkpvg+SVVdS0dA2CIPwAxGnGcHRrggAPQghB+ADWwE81X6REwfihY0m01mWFwiyIZBqqxYbE4XDKXVgewOIGOOnOiKh1woIDuCAAREyygznso1BptHp9F8-INvL4oHhcMCwRDoZ4gA).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. My actual use-case for this is much more complex so the other answer didn't help me. I ended up doing `public async func(): Promise<this>` and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your confusion can be resolved with a bit of object oriented programming polymorphism.

What you want is possible, you just need to declare your classes in another way:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
  abstract getIdPlusOne(): string | number;
}

class User extends BaseClass {
  id: number;

  constructor(id: number) { 
    super();
    this.id = id; 
  }

  getIdPlusOne(): number {
    return this.id;
  }
}

class Book extends BaseClass {
  id: string;

  constructor(id: string) { 
    super();
    this.id = id; 
  }

  getIdPlusOne(): string {
    return this.id
  }
}

console.log(new User(1).getIdPlusOne())
console.log(typeof new User(1).getIdPlusOne())
console.log(new Book("1").getIdPlusOne())
console.log(typeof new Book("1").getIdPlusOne())
```

you can try to check on this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hzjkg5)

And in case this helps you. My suggestion would be to turn your abstract class into an interface:

```
interface BaseClass {
  getIdPlusOne(): string | number;
}
```

and implement that interface in your other classes